# Passing a DateTime to controller via URL causing error in ASP .NET MVC 3 (culture)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, cultureinfo

My application is setted with pt-BR culture (Date is dd-mm-yyyy) in web.config:

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="false" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" fileEncoding="iso-8859-15" responseHeaderEncoding="utf-8" resourceProviderFactoryType="string" enableBestFitResponseEncoding="true" culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" />
```

All DateTime created on my system is in right format, but I created a controller method like that:

```
public ActionResult Test(DateTime date)
{
}
```

Calling that method direct in the browser is passing null when the date is with portuguese-br format, like that:

```
mysite/Test/?date=19/01/2012   => date = null in my controller

mysite/Test/?date=01/01/2012   => date is fine, but in US format (mm-dd-yyyy)
```

How can I fix that, to accept my date format?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There's a gotcha with the default model binder that is not easy to know about but once you know it you no longer make the same mistake:

- When you use a POST request, the default model binder uses your culture settings to parse the dates.
- When you use a GET request, the default model binder uses `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to parse the dates and ignores your current culture settings.

Since you are using a GET request and passing the date as a query string parameter, you should format it using the invariant culture format when sending it in the url. The correct way to format your date as a query string parameter is `yyyy-MM-dd`.

You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/melvynharbour/archive/2008/11/21/mvc-modelbinder-and-localization.aspx) which gets into more details.

Comment: If you implement the custom binder, make sure to register it for DateTime? as well, not just DateTime.

Comment: Hello, Darin. I've encountered the same problem as the original post and your answer and the article quoted helped me to understand the issue but I can't reach an answer yet. I'm working on ASP.NET Core 2.0 but I don't know how to apply the recomendations of the article. Hope you could take a look to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47442368/routing-datetime-parameter-passing-as-null-empty

Answer (score 9):

As someone who does a lot of work with US companies, I've had a lot of experience with date issues.

My best advice is to choose an unambiguous format when transmitting.

```
dd-MMM-yyyy
```

and

```
yyyy-MM-dd
```

Are safe bets, and will be successfully parsed by DateTime.Parse(obj).

If changing the date format is not an option, you should look at `DateTime.ParseExact`, which allows you to specify the exact format string you are after.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to accept the date as a string and then manipulate it in the controller to the correct locale/culture.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem using an `@Html.Action(..)` in a view. For this situation it can be solved by putting the `DateTime` in a model:

```
public class MyModel
{
  public DateTime Value {get;set;}
}
```

and in the view:

```
@Html.Action("MyAction", new { myModel })
```

Note the `new { }` around the instance of `MyModel`, this way the `DateTime` is not converted to a string. This solution only works for `Html.Action()` and **not** for `Html.ActionLink()` or `Url.Action()` since MVC is doing a `myModel.ToString()` in the URL.