# How to set the culture of all ValueProviderResult used in model binding to a given value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

It turns out that MVC's `DefaultModelBinder` uses different cultures in order to parse values (e.g. `double`, `DateTime`, etc.) for POST vs GET requests.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910482/passing-a-datetime-to-controller-via-url-causing-error-in-asp-net-mvc-3-cultur) is more info.

I see that this is controlled by the `Culture` property of `ValueProviderResult` objects, which are returned from `IValueProvider.GetValue()`.

**My question is:** How can I globally make sure that this value is always CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.

I know I can implement custom value providers and do it this way.

I know I can implement custom model binders and do it this way.

I know I can set the culture in the thread, but unfortunately this is not an option in my case.

What I am looking for is a way to set it so that even the default model binder and the existing value providers are able to parse in culture invariant way, irrespective of what the thread culture is set to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way that will match your criteria. You *will* have to do one of the things you know you can do (I'd say the most proper way would be a custom value provider).

Reason: All the default ValueProviders are hardcoded to use either `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` or `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`.

Here, specifically, is the way `FormValueProvider` does it:

```
internal FormValueProvider(
            ControllerContext controllerContext,
            IUnvalidatedRequestValues unvalidatedValues
         )
         : base(
              controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form, 
              unvalidatedValues.Form,
              CultureInfo.CurrentCulture // <--- Grrr, argh
         ) 
{
}
```

The culture isn't retrieved from anywhere else (i.e., the argument above isn't used as a default, but as the one culture to use).

**Cultures of the different IValueProviders**

For reference, these are the cultures for each of the default IValueProviders:

- ChildActionValueProvider: InvariantCulture
- FormValueProvider: **CurrentCulture**
- JsonValueProvider: **CurrentCulture**
- RouteDataValueProvider: InvariantCulture
- QueryStringValueProvider: InvariantCulture
- HttpFileCollectionValueProvider: InvariantCulture

**Replacing the `CurrentCulture` IValueProviders**

It isn't a huge task to replace `FormValueProvider`, since, as seen above, it just calls its base class' (`NameValueCollectionValueProvider`) constructor - which takes the desired culture as an argument.

The original implementation of FormValueProvider *appears* on the surface to be harder than it actually is, with references to internal classes and interfaces. But they're not needed in order to replace the provider - they're only there for unit testing.

You only need to call the base constructor (as mentioned above), passing two `NameValueCollection`s that are easy to acquire: `Request.Forms` and the `Forms` property of `Validation.Unvalidated(Request)` (a static method). And set the third argument to the culture you want.

The `FormValueProviderFactory` is even more straightforward.

`JsonValueProvider` is a bit more involved - basically you'd have to copy the source of `JsonValueProviderFactory` to a new class and modify it - because although it allows overriding `GetValueProvider()`, that method mainly consists of calls to other `private static` methods.

**EDIT (Petar Ivanov):** This worked for me. In order to make it work it was not enough to add the custom factory to `ValueProviderFactories.Factories`, because this way it's is added after the `FormValueProviderFactory`. Instead, I had to replace the `FormValueProviderFactory` with the custom one.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I guess I wasn't sure which of the default providers use the CurrentCulture (and I therefore need to extend), so I was looking for a more general solution.

Comment: Added the list. I removed `Session` and `TempData` - those are part of MVC Futures and so aren't used by default - same goes for `Cookie` and `ServerVariable`. All of those use `InvariantCulture`.