# Serialize() Jquery returns null for fields date type

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jsonserializer

I'm trying to serialize my form I have values ​​in my PartialViewResult (ASPNET MVC 4) but is coming DATE type fields to null, does anyone know why? Thanks!

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("CadastroLancamentoParcelar")',
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    context: this,
    data: $("#LancamentoForm").serialize(),
    success: function (result) {
        $(this).html(result);
    },
    close: function (event, ui) {
        $('#dialog-parcelar').empty();
    }
});
```

My PartialViewResult:

```
    [Security]
    [HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult CadastroLancamentoParcelar(LancamentoReceitaDespesa lancamento)
    {
        lancamento.decLancamentoParcelaValor = lancamento.decLancamentoReceitaDespesaValor;

        return PartialView("_CadastroLancamentoParcelar", lancamento);
    }
```

HTML MVC:

```
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.dtLancamentoReceitaDespesaDataVencimento, "{0: dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @maxlength = "10", @style = "width:107px;", @onkeypress = "mascara(this,mdata);", autocomplete = "off", @id = "txtCalendario" })
```

HTML:

```
 <input autocomplete="off" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Data do Vencimento: must be a date." id="txtCalendario" maxlength="10" name="dtLancamentoReceitaDespesaDataVencimento" onkeypress="mascara(this,mdata);" style="width:107px;" type="text" value="" class="hasDatepicker">
```

Comment: Check the generated HTML, or post it here as well

Comment: My guess is that there's some ASP.net code that's interfering.  Probably the date picker creates another element that holds the value until the form is submitted.  Make sure the HTML input is being updated.

Comment: could you post data being passed through ajax request?

Comment: Looks like he is serializing the date value ... is right? has to do with the mask? 19%2F12%2F2013

Answer (score 1):

already solved the problem...

There's a gotcha with the default model binder that is not easy to know about but once you know it you no longer make the same mistake:

When you use a POST request, the default model binder uses your culture settings to parse the dates.

When you use a GET request, the default model binder uses CultureInfo.InvariantCulture to parse the dates and ignores your current culture settings.

follow the link discovery: 
[Passing a DateTime to controller via URL causing error in ASP .NET MVC 3 (culture)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910482/passing-a-datetime-to-controller-via-url-causing-error-in-asp-net-mvc-3-cultur)